# Определение типа

Tags: c++, типы, преобразование-типов

Как определить тип результата арифметического выражения?

Comment: странный вопрос. Обычно самый общий из всех частей выражения.

Comment: Посмотреть в спецификации языка правила, по которым этот тип определяется.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Операнды арифметических типов в под-выражениях должны быть приведены к общему типу, чтобы можно было выполнить операцию и получить тип результирующего выражения.

Процесс получения общего типа для операндов операций и выведения результирующего типа носит название обычных арифметических преобразований - **usual arithmetic conversions**.

Порядок преобразование типов операндов арифметических типов в выражениях определяется следующим образом, как это описано в разделе *5 Expressions* стандарта C++:

> —(10.2) If either operand is of type long double, the other shall be
>   converted to long double.

То есть если один из операндов имеет тип `long double`, то второй операнд приводится к тому типу.

> —(10.3) Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other shall be
>   converted to double.

Иначе, если один из операндов имеет тип `double`, то второй операнд также должен быть приведен к этому типу.

> —(10.4) Otherwise, if either operand is float, the other shall be
>   converted to float.

Иначе, если один операнд имеет тип `float`, то второй операнд также должен быть приведен к этому типу.

> —(10.5) Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on
>   both operands.61 Then the following rules shall be applied to the
>   promoted operands:

Иначе применяется целочисленное приведение типов.

> —(10.5.1) If both operands have the same type, no further conversion
>   is needed.

Если после этого типы совпадают, то дальнейшие преобразования не производятся.

> —(10.5.2) Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or
>   both have unsigned integer types, the operand with the type of lesser
>   integer conversion rank shall be converted to the type of the operand
>   with greater rank.

Иначе если оба операнда имеют беззнаковый или знаковый тип, то операнд с меньшем рангом преобразуется к типу операнда с большим рангом.

> —(10.5.3) Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has
>   rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other
>   operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to
>   the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.

Иначе, если операнд беззнакового целого типа имеет ранг больший или равный рангу знакового целого типа второго операнда, то второй операнд преобразуется к типу беззнакового целого типа первого операнда.

> —(10.5.4) Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer
>   type can represent all of the values of the type of the operand with
>   unsigned integer type, the operand with unsigned integer type shall be
>   converted to the type of the operand with signed integer type.

Иначе если операнд знакового целого типа может представить все значения беззнакового целого типа второго операнда, то второй операнд преобразуется к типу первого операнда.

> —(10.5.5) Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned
>   integer type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed
>   integer type.

Иначе оба операнда должны быть преобразованы к беззнаковому целому типу, соответствующему знаковому целому типу первого операнда.

Вот простой пример

Имеются два объявления

```
long int x = 0;
unsigned int y = 0;
```

и оба типа, `long int` и `unsigned int`, занимают **4 байта**.

Спрашивается, какой тип будет у варажения

```
x + y
```

Уверяю вас, что многие программисты, которые не читали этот раздел стандарта, будут не в состоянии ответить на этот вопрос:)

Ответ: согласно последнему подпункту цитаты типом выражения будет `unsigned long int`.

Имейте в виду, что ранг типа `long int` всегда больше ранга `int` и, соответственно, ранга `unsigned int`.

Comment: Плюсанул. Какая редакция Стандарта?

Comment: @Majestio У меня сейчас под рукой Document Number: N4296 Date: 2014-11-19 .

Comment: Строго говоря, сначала сработает  пункт 10.5.3 и ответ `unsigned int`  (на практике, конечно, для 4-х байтных `long` и `int` разницы в кодогенерации нет, так что это пустое буквоедство в духе стандартов...)

Comment: @avp Что это за пункт 10.5.3?

Comment: @av И ответ unsigned int неверный. Как я написал, правильный ответ unsigned long int. Естественно при условии, что два типа имеют один и тот же размер.

Comment: Пункт 10.5.3? Ну как же, прямо из Вашего ответа: `(10.5.3) Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater than or equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, the operand with signed integer type shall be converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type.` / Согласны?

Comment: @avp Ранг типа int или unsigned int меньше ранга типа long int.

Comment: Да? Всегда думал, что ранг в данном контексте это размер (например, в битах). А что, это не так?

Comment: @avp  Согласно Стандарту "The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, ..."

Comment: @avp Я добавил  уточняющее  предложение в конец своего ответа.

Comment: Ну, с таким определением они (разработчики стандарта) и были вынуждены вводить пункты 10.5.4 и 10.5.5, что (больше букв) не упрощает понимания сути дела, особенно когда на сцене появляются битовые поля. Проще было бы понимать, если сказать, что приводим к наиболее длинному, а при равной длине к unsigned.

Answer (score 4):

Как `std::common_type<Arg1, Arg2, ...>::type` :)

Comment: @AnT Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы Вам не использовать `auto`, а затем, когда Вам понадобится тип результата - `decltype(...)` ?

Пример (весьма банальный):

```
auto res = 14.88 + 12;
std::vector<decltype(res)> vec;
```