# Можно ли при помощи static_assert проверить факт переполнения при умножении беззнаковых целых?

Tags: c++, переполнение, static-assert

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
static_assert(X > 0);
static_assert(Y > 0);
static_assert(((X * Y) / X) == Y);
```

Где `X` и `Y` - это аргументы шаблона, которые имеют тип `size_t`.

Предполагается, что данный код проверяет возможное переполнение беззнаковых целых (на этапе компиляции).

Мой вопрос заключается в следующем: есть ли гарантия, что компилятор сперва честно вычислит произведение `X * Y`, и только потом честно его разделит на `X`?

Поскольку `X` и `Y` - беззнаковые, то, на мой взгляд, компилятор обязан учитывать потерю значимости при возможном переполнении. Поэтому, он обязан сначала умножить, а потом разделить. Но уверенности у меня нет.

Comment: Компилятор-то вычисляет именно так, только вот для этого `X` и `Y` должны быть известны во время компиляции...

Comment: @Harry, они известны, потому что являются аргументами шаблона.

Comment: Тогда дело другое.

Comment: @user7860670, каковы ваши доказательства?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Компилятор имеет право упростить выражение `X * Y / X == Y` до `true` в том и только в том случае, если он уверен, что такое упрощение не нарушает наблюдаемого поведения программы.

Смотрите, например, *[intro.abstract] / 1*:

> The semantic descriptions in this document define a parameterized nondeterministic abstract machine. This document places no requirement on the structure of conforming implementations. In particular, they need not copy or emulate the structure of the abstract machine. Rather, conforming implementations are required to emulate (only) the observable behavior of the abstract machine as explained below.*4*
>
> 4) This provision is sometimes called the “as-if” rule, because an implementation is free to disregard any requirement of this document as long as the result is *as if* the requirement had been obeyed, as far as can be determined from the observable behavior of the program. For instance, an actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no side effects affecting the observable behavior of the program are produced.

Также, об недопустимости оптимизаций, нарушающих наблюдаемое поведение программы говорится в *[expr.pre] / 5*:

> [*Note*: The implementation may regroup operators according to the usual mathematical rules only where the operators really are associative or commutative.*51* For example, in the following fragment
>
> ```
> int a, b;
> /* ... */
> a = a + 32760 + b + 5;
> ```
>
> the expression statement behaves exactly the same as
>
> ```
> a = (((a + 32760) + b) + 5);
> ```
>
> due to the associativity and precedence of these operators. Thus, the result of the sum `(a + 32760)` is next added to `b`, and that result is then added to `5` which results in the value assigned to `a`. On a machine in which overflows produce an exception and in which the range of values representable by an `int` is `[-32768, +32767]`, the implementation cannot rewrite this expression as
>
> ```
> a = ((a + b) + 32765);
> ```
>
> since if the values for `a` and `b` were, respectively, `-32754` and `-15`, the sum `a + b` would produce an exception while the original expression would not; nor can the expression be rewritten as either
>
> ```
> a = ((a + 32765) + b);
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> a = (a + (b + 32765));
> ```
>
> since the values for `a` and `b` might have been, respectively, `4` and `-8` or `-17` and `12`. However on a machine in which overflows do not produce an exception and in which the results of overflows are reversible, the above expression statement can be rewritten by the implementation in any of the above ways because the same result will occur. *—end note*]

Теперь давайте разберёмся с "наблюдаемым поведением" в выражении `X * Y / X == Y`. Пусть выражения `X` и `Y` имеют тип `unsigned int` и значения этих выражений больше нуля.

Если произведение `X * Y` не превосходит величины `UINT_MAX` (т.е. переполнения нет), то, равенство `X * Y / X == Y` является истинным.
Пусть теперь произведение `X * Y` превосходит величину `UINT_MAX`. Если бы мы производили вычисления в вещественных числах, то можно было бы выписать следующие соотношения:

```
`X * Y == k * (UINT_MAX + 1) + r`, где `k >= 1`, `0 <= r <= UINT_MAX`,
(k * (UINT_MAX + 1) + r) / X == Y,
k * (UINT_MAX + 1) / X + r / X == Y.
```

Однако, вычисления над беззнаковыми целыми производятся по правилам модулярной арифметики, *[basic.fundamental] / 2*:

> [...] An unsigned integer type has the same width `N` as the corresponding signed integer type. The range of representable values for the unsigned type is `0` to `2^N − 1` (inclusive); arithmetic for the unsigned type is performed modulo `2^N`. [*Note*: Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow. Overflow for signed arithmetic yields undefined behavior (7.1). *—end note*]

Это означает, что при переполнении произведение `X * Y` будет равно не `k * (UINT_MAX + 1) + r`, а только `r`. Следовательно, выражение `X * Y / X == Y` эквивалентно выражению `r / X == Y`, которое является ложным (ведь при переполнении `k * (UINT_MAX + 1) / X` больше единицы, но мы его просто отбросили!)

Таким образом, для проверки остутствия переполнения при умножении двух ненулевых выражений `X` и `Y` типа `unsigned int` вполне можно использовать проверку `X * Y / X == Y`. И в общем случае компилятор не имеет права предполагать, что это равенство всегда истинно.

---

Пусть в некоторой реализации количество бит, определяющих значение типа `unsigned short` равно 16, а количество бит, определяющих значение типа `int` равно 32. Тогда, если `X` и `Y` имеют тип `unsigned short`, то выражение `X * Y / X == Y` может быть истинным даже в том случае, когда произведение `X * Y` не может быть представлено типом `unsigned short`.

Прежде чем вычислить произведение `X * Y` арифметические операнды бинарного оператора `*` приводятся к общему типу с помощью [обычных арифметических преобразований](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604456/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0). В данном конкретном случае общий тип — это `int`.

Пусть `X` и `Y` равны `65535` и `2` соответственно. Величина `65535 * 2` не может быть представлена типом `unsigned short`, но зато прекрасно помещается в 32-битный тип `int`, а именно операнды такого типа и перемножаются. Затем значение `65535 * 2` делится на `65535` и получается значение `2`, которое, очевидно, равно `Y`.

Пусть `X` и `Y` оба равны `65535`. Величина `65535 * 65535` не может быть представлена типом `unsigned short`, но и 32-битным типом `int` она тоже не может быть представлена. Хотя изначально мы перемножаем значения беззнаковых типов,   неопределённое поведение всё же происходит — переполнение знакового целочисленного типа, к которому были приведены операнды посредством обычных арифметических преобразований.

---

Тип `std::size_t` всего лишь псевдоним некоторого другого целочисленного типа. И стандарт языка не специфицирует какого именно. Стандарт языка допускает существование реализаций у которых в процессе обычных арифметических преобразований операнды типа `std::size_t` преобразуются к знаковому целочисленному типу (однако, я не могу привести ни одного *реального* примера компилятора с таким поведением). Таким образом, проверять отсутствие переполнения с помощью выражения `X * Y / X == Y` потенциально опасно.

---

P.S.
Проверить на отсутствие переполнения произведения `X * Y`, где `X` и `Y` имеют тип `std::size_t` можно с помощью выражения:

```
std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / X >= Y
```

А если допускается обращение операндов в ноль, то так:

```
X == 0 || std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() / X >= Y
```

Comment: "Тип std::size_t всего лишь псевдоним некоторого другого целочисленного типа." - [неотрицательного целого](http://eel.is/c++draft/support#types.layout-3), а не любого целого. Почему тогда "`X * Y / X == Y` потенциально опасно"?

Comment: @вася, да, `std::size_t` — беззнаковый целый тип, но в процессе обычных арифметических преобразований он может быть преобразован к знаковому целому типу. Например, если `std::size_t` — это 16-битный `unsigned short`, а `int` — 32-битный, то поведение кода `std::size_t X, Y; X = Y = 65535; X * Y / X == Y` не определено.

Comment: Звучит логично. Но в таком случае без предварительных проверок перемножать *implementation defined* типы вообще нельзя :(

Comment: Похоже, что правила продвижения типов могли бы сделать лучше (unsigned short -> unsigned int сразу), но это наследие `C` :( https://stackoverflow.com/q/33732489

Comment: @вася, [хороший ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/627526) с пояснениями относительно расширения "малых" беззнаковых типов до знакового `int`.