# Как найти дискриминант

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Даны коэффициенты квадратного уравнения. Выясните, сколько корней у этого квадратного уравнения.

Входные данные:
На ввод дано три целых числа a, b и c именно в таком порядке.
−10^6 ≤ a,b,c≤ 10^6,a≠0

Выходные данные:
Выведите одно целое число: количество корней квадратного уравнения ax^2+bx+c=0.

Вот мой код:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
long double dis;

dis = b * b - 4 * a * c;

if (dis > 0)
    cout << 2;
else if (dis == 0)
    cout << 1;
else
    cout << 0;

return 0;
}
```

Я нашел проблему(как мне кажется), что при значении b = 10^6 и при попытке возвести b^2 тип duble не выдерживает и выдает ошибку, есть ли какой-нибудь способ решить эту проблему?
(Как в итоге оказалось проблема в том, что умножал два int, в комментариях написано)

Comment: может long double?

Comment: Нет, не подошел, значит ошибка у меня не в этом

Comment: А зачем отдельно `if((-4 * a * c) > 0)`? И еще — раз коэффициенты у вас — целые числа, используйте `long long`, и не пытайтесь ничего приводить к `double`.

Comment: Уже пытался приводить к long long, но все равно выдавал ошибку. ведь при проверке чтоб было два корня dis хотя бы на чуть-чуть должен быть больше 0

Comment: Покажите, как пробовали. "на чуть-чуть" с целыми числами  - что-то не то...

Comment: Переменная `b` имеет тип `int`, следовательно выражение `b * b` также имеет тип `int`. Обычный 32-битный тип `int` не может вместить столь большие значения как `10^6 * 10^6`. Используйте тип `long long` для переменных `a`, `b` и `c`, чтобы промежуточные вычисления производились в домене типа `long long`, а также используйте этот тип для переменной `dis`. По возможности не следует привлекать арифметику с плавающей точкой в целочисленные задачи. Также изучите механизм _usual arithmetic conversions_: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/627522), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604456).

Comment: А не проще сравнить `ABS(b)` и `2*SQRT(a*c)`? тебе ж ни сами корни, ни даже просто дискриминант не надо считать. Тебе надо просто знать, что больше, `b*b` или `4*a*c`...

Comment: @Akina Если надо просто знать, что больше, `b*b` или `4*a*c`, то почему бы эти величины и не сравнить? Зачем сравнивать `ABS(b)` и `2*SQRT(a*c)`?

Comment: @wololo Верно, на а*с тоже можно словить переполнение..

Answer (score 2):

Не хотел, но, похоже, придется отвечать, а то тут так и будут плавающую точку к целым числам тулить...

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    long long a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
    a = b*b - 4*a*c;
    cout << (a == 0 ? 1 : a > 0 ? 2 : 0) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я не согласен с мнением Harry и остальных, кто говорит что `double` не подходит для решения задачи. `double` поддерживает точную целочисленную арифметику для значений *< 2<sup>53</sup>*. Для входных данных верно *|a|, |b|, |c| ≤ 10<sup>6</sup>*. Любые промежуточные значения не превосходят *5·10<sup>12</sup>*, что меньше чем *2<sup>53</sup>*:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    double d = b * b - 4. * a * c;
    std::cout << (d == 0 ? 1 : d > 0 ? 2 : 0) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Я не говорю, что "не подходит", я говорю — при условии целочисленных данных плавающая точка излишня.

Comment: @Harry, такое рассуждение: целые типы при переполнении отбрасывают старшие биты результата (оставим в стороне UB), вещественные типы отбрасывают младшие типы результата и компенсируют результат в показателе степени. При прочих равных, я бы сказал что второе поведение лучше с точки зрения пользователя - graceful degradation, первое поведение - катастрофа. Что скажете?

Comment: В данной задаче переполнения нет, поэтому ваши (верные) рассуждения не для этого вопроса. Естественно, я говорил о данной задаче, а то вы так еще и возразите, что корни найти не получится :)

Comment: Целочисленный вариант в случае переполнения довольно быстро обнажит проблему, в то время как вариант с плавающей точкой может её довольно долго и умело маскировать. И проявится она в самый неожиданный момент. P.S. И вообще, исключительно из вредности, я бы решения данной задачи тестировал в [таком окружении](https://godbolt.org/z/xrdToGGzb).

Comment: @wololo, вы фактически сделали из `double` `float` и говорите что в такой конфигурации решение не работает. Воля ваша, отстреливайте себе ноги сколько угодно. Целочисленный вариант не обнажит проблему быстро. Он будет врать крайне неочевидными способами. Вещественный вариант будет врать только тогда когда вершина параболы действительно близка к нулю.

Comment: `Он будет врать крайне неочевидными способами.` — что это значит?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, а ведь вы говорите в рамках действующих ограничений `|a|, |b|, |c| ≤ 10^6`? Вы сначала говорили, что при таких условиях результат будет точным, а теперь говорите, что будет врать только если вершина параболы действительно близка к нулю. Или ограничения к последнему утверждению не относятся? P.s ни в коем случае не хочу вас задеть, просто интересно узнать.

Comment: @maestro, результат будет точным пока *5 * M^2 < 2^53*, где *|a|, |b|, |c| < M* (откуда M = 42443372). Если модули станут больше *M*, при вычислениях возникнут округления. Тогда метод начнёт "когда вершина параболы действительно близка к нулю".

Comment: @wololo, я хотел сказать, что трёхмерное множество (множество троек *a, b, c*) в котором метод работает правильно сложно устроено. У нас нет простого способа понять что произошло переполнение (про UB не говорим). Тоже множество для вещественного решения устроено проще. Хотя границы у него всё равно страшные.

Comment: **1)** Всё ещё не понимаю ход ваших рассуждений. `(множество троек a, b, c) в котором метод работает правильно сложно устроено.` Что мешает для целочисленного способа выписать такие же ограничения на `a`, `b` и `c`, как для способа в числах с плавающей точкой? Для 64-битного знакового целочисленного типа получим: `|a|, |b|, |c| < 1'358'187'914` — при таких ограничениях на коэффициенты переполнения не произойдёт и результат будет точным. `Целочисленный вариант не обнажит проблему быстро.` Ладно, попробуем проверить работоспособность формул «в лоб». ...

Comment: ... Будем генерировать случайным образом 32(64)-битные знаковые целые тройки коэффициентов, считать формулу в 32(64)-битных знаковых целых и во `float` (`double`). [Пример](https://godbolt.org/z/oGcM6vh7a). Видим, что целочисленный способ даёт ошибочный результат  примерно в половине случаев, а способ в числах с плавающей точкой даёт ошибку хорошо если в одном случае из 100 миллионов. Если мы можем выборочно проверять правильность алгоритма на некоторых входных данных, то даже не зная подлежащего алгоритма, целочисленный метод быстрее проявит проблему, чего не скажешь о плавающем. ...

Comment: ... Хотя да, в плавающих числа красиво выглядит. Вылезет это потом боком, но graceful degradation. **2)** `и говорите что в такой конфигурации решение не работает.` Я говорю, что по стандарту языка никто вам не обещает IEEE 754 binary64 `double`. И это не просто теоретическая возможность, а вполне практическая. Да, никто не заставляет использовать странные опции компилятора, но сам факт того, что это возможно, заставляет лишний раз думать о предельных случаях (и мне это не нравится, воля моя), которых можно было бы легко избежать, считай мы всё в целых числах. ...

Comment: ... **3)** `отстреливайте себе ноги сколько угодно.` Ну ежели барин дал добро....

Comment: @wololo, ваши аргументы правильны. Но вы проверяете результат на удвоенной разрядности, чего нормальный программист делать не станет. Кроме того, удвоенной разрядности хватит для *4ac*?

Answer (score -3):

Привет попробуй этот код у меня всё работает

```
        #include <iostream>
        using namespace std;

         int main ()
         {
         int a, b, c;
         cin >> a >> b >> c;
         long double dis;
         dis = b * b - 4 * a * c;
         if (dis > 0)
          cout << 2;
         else if (dis == 0)
         cout << 1;
         else
          cout << 0;
            return 0;
           }
```

Comment: Работает ли? А если все значения ввести по 1000000? Зачем тебе dis типа double, если там double неоткуда взяться?

Comment: Да и вообще это тот же самый код, что и в вопросе.